# Moving variables from one page to another

Tags: redirect, pages, variables

How can I link to another WordPress page but move variables to it as well (preferably not through the address bar)?
For instance, I have on one page a list of shops in which a user should be able to click on a shop, which would then open the shop page with the correct data.
So the shop's id needs to move from the shops list page to the shop page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could `POST` the shop id to the target page. otherwise- cookie, session. or just fetch it on the list page via ajax.

**edit -** a simple post request via a form:

in your source page:

```
<form action="b.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="42" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

in the target page b.php:

```
<?php 
if( isset($_POST['id']) ):
    echo $_POST['id'];
endif;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the latter? I need to pass the shop ID from the list page to the shop page. How would I do it with ajax?

Comment: Not via ajax, I was suggesting not taking the viewer to another page and just fetching the contents of the shop page for the selected shop via ajax and displaying it on the list of shops page.

Comment: I see. So if I do want to open the shop on a different page my only two options are posting variables through the address bar and using cookies?

Comment: passing variables via the address bar is a `GET` request, ie: `page?myvar=foo`. a `POST` request passes the variable in a way that's hidden to the viewer and shows the plain URL. or a cookie.

Comment: Can you please give an example for using the post method?

Comment: see edited answer.

Comment: Milo, hi. Still on the subject - the thing is that the value I want to pass to another PHP page is not there when the initial php code runs. I only have it when the javascript code runs on the client side. How can I pass the parameter from the javascript code? Can I still use the POST method?